# When trying to use Python 3.4 to import RPi.GPIO I get "ImportError: No module"

Tags: gpio, python, pi-3

I am trying to get the rpi.gpio to work with Python 3.4 on Raspberry Pi 3. I have tried every command to install and when I am in the active idle terminal, it seems to load just fine. But when I run the script from the Pi terminal, I get this.

> ImportError: No module name rpi.gpio

I'm using Raspbian.  This makes no sense to me, but I can only assume it is user error. Everything works just fine in Python 2.7. I don't understand why I can't get it to work on 3.4.

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that when programming, everything is case-sensitive. Based on the given error message, I can assume that your line of code says "import rpi.gpio", but due to the case-sensitivity, you must change it to "import RPi.GPIO"

Comment: *everything is case-sensitive* is a blanket statement which is not strictly true. "Python language is case-sensitive" would be better scoped IMO.

Comment: It's probably a case-sensitive thing - otherwise could be related to the python-version-specific version of the module.

Also you should try gpiozero - a higher-level API for GPIO: http://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 1):

The error that you are showing is due to case-sensitivity. The proper module name is 'RPi-GPIO'. However, in the case that that does not work you will need to install the RPi-GPIO library:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-rpi.gpio
```

If using apt-get doesn't work you will need to install it via pip

```
sudo pip install RPi.GPIO
```

We have also seen that pip was not included with Python 3.4, in which you will have to install the dependencies: (I would suggest updating before doing so)

```
sudo apt-get update     
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev openssl
```

Then finally we can run pip to install RPi-GPIO

```
sudo pip install RPi.GPIO
```