# No module named RPI after install

Tags: gpio, python-3

[image: I have tried to manually install the package but still failed to call module RPI]

```
sudo apt-get -y install python3-rpi.gpio
```

I used the above command to install the package, it shows that is already the newest version, however i still get the error no module named RPI. Anyone has the same problem?

**SOLVED:**
Use

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
```

Instead of

```
import RPI.GPIO as GPIO
```

Comment: I can't see the code but I believe your problem is capitalization; try import RPi.GPIO as GPIO (note lowercase i in Pi).

Comment: Please post code in a **{}** block as text not pictures.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When trying to use Python 3.4 to import RPi.GPIO I get "ImportError: No module"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/57191/when-trying-to-use-python-3-4-to-import-rpi-gpio-i-get-importerror-no-module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip install RPi.GPIO`

Change 
`import RPI.GPIO as GPIO`
to
`import RPi.GPIO as GPIO`